# why lvalue required as increment operand error?

Tags: c, increment, lvalue, decrement, operand

Why lvalue required as increment operand Error In ***a=b+(++c++);*** ?

***Just Wanted to assign 'b+(c+1)' to 'a' and Increment 'C' by 2 at the same time.***

***I'M A Beginner Just Wanted A Clarification About What "LVALUE ERROR" Actually Is?***

```
main()
{

int a=1,b=5,c=3;

a=b+(++c++);  

printf("a=%d   b= %d   c= %d \n",a,b,c);
}
```

Comment: Err...what exactly are you trying to do? It seems like you want to increase c by two, but I don't think this would work. You EITHER do a preincrement, OR a postincrement. But I've never seen (or even considered using) both. My guess is, that it simply doesn't know what to do with that code.

Comment: I just Wanted to assign 'b+(c+1)' to 'a' and Increment 'C' by 2 at the same time.

Comment: @leppie - Though the behaviour of such code is undefined, the question itself is not about undefined behaviour, but about lvalues.

Comment: *Beginners* should never consider writing such code and *experts* know not to write such ridiculous code in the first instance.  Even if it could work, what do you think the advantage would be? Even if it worked it would comber under ["too clever"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alfredth/archive/2009/01/08/are-you-smart-enough-to-debug-your-own-code.aspx).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Postfix increment binds tighter than prefix increment so what you would want would be something like:

```
a = b + (++c)++;
```

This is not legal C, though, as the the result of prefix increment (like the result of postfix increment in your example) is not an *lvalue*. This means that it's just a value; it doesn't refer to a particular object like 'c' any more so trying to change it makes no sense. It would have no visible effect as no object would be updated.

Personally I think that doing it in two statements is clearer in any case.

```
a = b + c + 1;
c += 2;
```

Answer (score 4):

LVALUE means, that there isn't a variable the operation is supposed to be performed on.

C files are basically nothing but text files, which require a particular formatting, so the compiler can understand it.

Writing something like ++Variable++ is complete nonsense for the compiler.

You can basically imagine ++c as:

```
Var += 1;
return Var;
```

while c++ is:

```
int Buf = Var;
Var += 1;
return Buf;
```

To 'repair' your code:

```
void main() {
    int a=1,b=5,c=3;
    a = b + (++c);  //Equals 5 + 4
    printf("a=%d   b= %d   c= %d \n",a,b, ++c);  //a = 9, b = 5, c = 5
}
```

This way, you'll get the result you wanted, without the compiler complaining.

Please remember, that when using ++c or c++ in a combined operation, the order DOES matter.
When using ++c, the higher value will be used in the operation, when using c++, it will operate with the old value.

That means:

```
int a, c = 5;
a = 5 + ++c;  //a = 11
```

while

```
int a, c = 5;
a = 5 + c++;  //a = 10
```

Because in the latter case, c will only be '6' AFTER it is added to 5 and stored in a.

Comment: Technically `++Variable++` is not two function calls at the same time, it isn't any function calls at all. The expression has a defined binding: `++(Variable++)` which is illegal for different reasons but nothing to do with operations (or functions) being applied (or called) simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah, if we wanted to be technical about it. I tried to make it understandable, but of course you're right. Let's stick with: 'The compiler won't accept it'.